# Получить верхний пиксель у изображения

Tags: java, graphics

Возможно ли как-то получить верхний пиксель (верхнюю границу) у изображения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим у меня есть такое изображение, размер - 64х64 пикселя. Как видно, это треугольник, без фона в правой верхней части, поэтому нужно на каждую последующую координату `x` получать `y` равный верхнему пикселю ТРЕУГОЛЬНИКА (не учитывая фон, которого в принципе и нет).

Comment: Так в чём задача-то, Использовать `topY = x` или отличить фон от нефона?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример преобразования картинки в 2D-массив пикселей.

```
public int[][] loadBMPImage(String BMPFileName) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(BMPFileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int[][] array2D = new int[image.getHeight()][image.getWidth()];

    for (int xPixel = 0; xPixel < image.getHeight(); xPixel++) {
        for (int yPixel = 0; yPixel < image.getWidth(); yPixel++) {
            int color = image.getRGB(yPixel, xPixel);
        }
    }
    return array2D;
}
```

Переводите `int` в `Color` и вперед!